# ASP.Net MVC JS/CSS bundling not working when deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I've deployed a small web app which was written in ASP.Net MVC 4.  We have our JS/CSS bundles setup properly and they work fine locally.  The problem is when I deploy to an IIS 6 server the bundles don't seem to work.  The js/css doesn't download and when I try to go to the js link in the script I get a 404.

Has anyone deployed MVC 4 to IIS 6 and had this work?

Comment: I'd imagine this would be a routing issue, I believe you have to make changes to the routing setup to run MVC on IIS6, I'm afraid I don't have the details to hand though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that we were running as a Virtual Directory configured for ASP.Net 4.0 under a Default Web Site which was configured for ASP.Net 2.0.

We created a new web site and set it to asp.net 4.0 and everything worked perfectly. As per this post on [Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) extensionless urls should just work on most instances of IIS 6 now.

Answer (score 2):

The bundles are served through extensionless urls like:

- http://foo.com/Scripts/js?v=GP89PKpk2iEmdQxZTRyBnKWSLjO7XdNG4QC1rv6LPxw1
- http://foo.com/Content/css?v=oI5uNwN5NWmYrn8EXEybCIbINNBbTM_DnIdXDUL5RwE1
- ...

IIS 6 does not support extensionless urls out-of-the box. When it encounters an url ending with `/js` or `/css` it has strictly no clue that it has to associate this url with the `aspnet_isapi.dll` handler (ASP.NET).

You may read Phil Haack's [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) in which he explains how you could configure IIS 6 for ASP.NET MVC in order to enable extensionless urls. It's about ASP.NET MVC 3, but exactly the same stands true for ASP.NET MVC 4.

Oh, and you might consider upgrading to IIS 7.0+ which has this feature by default when running in integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: That link assumes you have an extension like .axd which is part of the url.  Bundles are truly extensionless though so what he says doesn't work.  We already have a Wildcard mapping setup and it's not helping either.

Comment: @ShaneCourtrille, unfortunately currently I don't have access to an IIS 6 box in order to test this but I thought that by properly configuring extensionless urls you would be able to achieve that. Maybe you could try asking your question on http://serverfault.com as your question seems more related to server configuration than programming.

Comment: No, just having extensionless doesn't work for me either, unfortunately.  I haven't found a solution for this either.

Comment: I messed about with this for a while, in the end, I reverted to the old fashioned way...until we upgrade to IIS 7 in work!

Answer (score 0):

Mine problem was in BundleConfig.cs file in App_Start. My BindleConfig.cs file was looking previously like following

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/ui-js").Include(
                                     "~/Scripts/ui-js/jquery.min.1.11.1.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap.min.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap-slider.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/common-script.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/html5.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/jquery.colorbox.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/respond.src.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/angular.min.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap.js"
                                     ,"~/Scripts/ui-js/jRate.min.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/jcrop.min.js"
                                     ));
```

And my Layout page had

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/ui-js")
```

After googling i found the solution as you cant use same folder structure for **new ScriptBundle()** virtual path.

So i changed above to this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/ppScript").Include(
                                     "~/Scripts/ui-js/jquery.min.1.11.1.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap.min.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap-slider.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/common-script.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/html5.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/jquery.colorbox.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/respond.src.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/angular.min.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/bootstrap.js"
                                     ,"~/Scripts/ui-js/jRate.min.js"
                                     , "~/Scripts/ui-js/jcrop.min.js"
                                     ));
```

And in my Layout page i called it as

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/uiScript")
```

**NOTE:** You need to do this same with your CSS and modernizr bundle too :)